# How can I pass jquery variable as parameter to Java controller by href?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

This is my variable in javascript:

```
var dataid = dataInfo[i];
```

I want to pass the variable to my java controller through href:

```
 row = row + "<tr><td>" + dataid + "</td><td>" +
       schoolid + "</td><td>" + 
      "<td><a class='details' id='" + dataid + "'  href='@{DataManagement.dataDetails(dataId)}'>Details</a></td>"+
        "<td>"+
        </tr>";
```

but controller gets null value.

I am trying this using ajax:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url:  "@{DataManagement.dataDetails}",
            data: {
                id: dataId
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);

            }


        });
```

This is my controller:

```
public static void dataDetails(Long id) throws SQLException {

        Logger.info("id: "+ id);

        //dataId=dataId.trim();

        //Long iid = Long.parseLong(dataId);
        Data data = Data.findById(id);


        String totalStudent = Data.getTotalStudent(1L);

        Logger.info("totalStudent: " + totalStudent);

        renderArgs.put("totalStudent",totalStudent);

        render(data,totalStudent);

    }
```

But after ajax call it is not render the new page.

How can I do this?

Comment: you can't, java is executed on the server side, js is on the client side

Comment: you can't pass a js variable as a param to a java function

Comment: are you using some template engine that preprocesses this code in the server side? because js can't access java code

Comment: Then what should I do?

Comment: You might want to look into AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works!!!

I changed it to :

```
<td><a class='details' id='" + dataid + "'  href='/datamanagement/dataDetails/"+dataid+"'>Details</a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send a json request with ajax and accept it on Controller.

Ajax Request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(yourObject),
    url: "/path",
    success: function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
        window.location = "/redirectTo";
    },
    error : function(e) {
        console.log('Error: ' + e);
    }

});
```

On Controller:

```
@ResponseBody
@CrossOrigin @RequestMapping(value = "/path", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
private ResponseEntity<YourObject> someMethod(@RequestBody YourObject obj){
        // do your coding here
        return new ResponseEntity<YourObject>(modifiedObject, HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<YourObject>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```